# Simple find and copy script for linux

Tags: unix, centos

I'm quite a newbie to scripts in Linux. What im trying to get is a simple script that finds a file by its exact name, then copy that file to a different folder.

So Essentially it should work like "./findandcopy [filename]"
This is what i got so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

ARGS=1
E_BADARGS=65
E_NOFILE=66

if [ $# -ne "$ARGS" ]  # Correct number of arguments not passed
 then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` filename"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi


'find ./ -name \$1'  -exec cp {} /home/marc/ \;
```

but that wont work for me. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Just use `find .` instead of `find ./` -- you don’t need to type a slash at the end of a directory name, and, if you get in the habit of typing `./` when you mean the current directory (for which `.` will suffice), then someday you’ll accidentally type `/` or `/.`, with possibly disastrous results. You don’t need the `/` at the end of `/home/marc/`, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
find ./ -name "$1" -exec cp {} /home/marc/ \;
```

Without single quotes around it. Otherwise the shell will treat the entire `find ./ -name \$1` command as a single file name and try to execute that.

You should quote the argument `"$1"` to prevent whitespace or globs in the filename from expanding.

Comment: works now, thx for the quick response :) guess i should check out some basic script tutorials^^

Comment: I'd recommend this one: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ — you'll find examples for almost anything there. Please note that when asking questions in the future, it's always better to be a little more specific than "it won't work for me". If you're getting any errors, please include them.

Comment: thx for the tip, and regarding the errors that was kinda my problem since it simply did nothing, no error or any kind of output.